# How to Change icon color according to variable value in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I want to change the icon button color according to the variable value.
eg: if the variable value is greater than 40 icon color should be red other wise icon color is white.
I get a variable values from SQLite table.
following code, i have tried but its shows null check operator used on null value.\

```dart
                      int? tatalLeave=0;                

                         IconButton(
                          onPressed: (() {
                            getTotalLeave();
                          }),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.notifications_active_rounded,
                            color:
                                tatalLeave! >= 40 ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                            size: 30.0,
                          ),
                        )
```

following i have added sqlite codes

```
//get total number of leaves
  getTotalLeave() async {
    int? count = await DatabaseHelper.instance.countAllLeave();
    setState(() {
      tatalLeave = count;
      print(tatalLeave);
    });
  }
}
```

db helper class

```
Future<int?> countAllLeave() async {
    Database db = await database;
    final allLeave = Sqflite.firstIntValue(
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(num_leave_days) FROM leave_Details'));
    return allLeave;
  }
```

please help me to slove my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifiying the code as below,
As the getTotalLeave function is asynchronous you need to put await.

(await is to interrupt the process flow until the async method completes)

```dart
                      int? tatalLeave=0;                

                         IconButton(
                          onPressed: (()async {
                          await  getTotalLeave();
                          }),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.notifications_active_rounded,
                            color:
                                tatalLeave! >= 40 ? Colors.red : 
                          Colors.white,
                            size: 30.0,
                          ),
                        )
```

Comment: i want to change color according to totalLeave variable value.this variable value taking as null.

Comment: try `(tatalLeave??0) >= 40 ?` also you can do null check

Comment: can you explain this line